# posting scores not working/ gives "Invalid OAuth access token signature."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, air, facebook-access-token

whats wrong in this?

```
FacebookDesktop.api("/me/scores",callBack,{access_token:appAccessToke,score:100}, "POST")
```

app has the following permissions: publish_stream,publish_actions

app is categorized as Games

app is built using AIR
app access token is obtained thisway:

```
FacebookDesktop.api("/oauth/access_token", getAccessTokenHandler,{client_id:"xxxxxxx",client_secret:"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",grant_type:"client_credentials"});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your facebook app settings change authentication to web instead of naitve. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284578241552780